# How to make an Administrator in Google Groups that can send email only to a Group

Tags: google-groups

How to create an Admin in Google Groups that can send email to a Google Group.

The other members of the Google Group can read the email only and *not* be able to send to this Google Group. Only Group Admins should be able to send email.

Answer (score 1):

In your group, go the the "Manage" tool.

On the left menu, under "Permissions", click "Basic permissions".

There, you can set the permissions for viewing topics, posting, and joining the group.

Simply change the value under "Post" to "Owners of the Groups" and "Managers of the Group".

Then anyone who you want to be able to post should be an Owner or Manager.